# When i am trying to run "npm run serve", that time i am getting an error like the code below. How can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

Here is the error I got in my cmd,

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (97:23)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
|     customer_data() {
>       if (this.getData?.rowdata?.length > 0) {
|         return this.getData;
|       } else {

 @ ./src/views/ManageCustomer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-285 1:0-285 1:286-560 1:286-560
 @ ./src/views/ManageCustomer.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.10.73:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I'm unable to run my vue project of this reason.

Comment: Probably you get this error because optional chaining is not supported in your version of vue/nodejs. https://javascript.info/optional-chaining

Comment: provide more codes from the specific or related files in which the error occurs. otherwise, it is difficult to find the problem only by looking at this portion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NazemMahmudPiash Hello Sir, Please check this link. Here i pasted full error
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1alcEqny5nkJLL_mBgB77ZjxSYx3h6Hgd7OrgaCfqf9g/edit?usp=sharing